# Silverlight/ moonlight with firefox 5?

Tags: 11.04, firefox, moonlight

is there a solution to get these things working in natty with firefox 5

with firefox 3.6 everything was fine, 
but now with the firefox updates the moonlight add-on isnt working anymore.

How can i fix this?

Comment: please can you confirm where you have downloaded moonlight - and which version (add this to your question).  Also, which websites are not working (add the links)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/80293/17537

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick, but it's not a 100% with all silverlight implementations

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get upgrade
3. sudo apt-get install libmoon moonlight-plugin-mozilla moonlight-plugin-core

thanks to [samiux](http://samiux.blogspot.com/2010/09/howto-microsoft-silverlight-on-ubuntu.html)

Comment: Wow! Thank you. I had never even considered looking in the repos, for some reason. I think perhaps because of the way Firefox reacts when it isn't present. Great tip!

Comment: i already had that stuff installed and up to date.

Comment: therefore nothing changed.