# Can I use Silverlight in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, moonlight

I know that we can use moonlight to play silverlight content on website.

However, I know that moonlight can install on latest firefox. However it does not reliably work actually after i follow their procedure to install it again.

[Moonlight extension not working with new Firefox versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80293/moonlight-extension-not-working-with-new-firefox-versions)

Does anyone able to play silverlight content in Firefox using 11.10?

Comment: The above link still works in Firefox 10 - which websites are you having difficulties with?

Comment: Do you really need silverlight?! If I were you, I should have avoided silverlight!

Comment: yes, some browser require silver light to run , so annoying

Comment: @fossfreedom Netflix _refuses_ to use Moonlight for its streaming content.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude - yep - moonlight doesnt have the DRM capabilities to play netflix.  The Q will help you though: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1488/is-there-a-way-to-stream-netflix

Comment: @fossfreedom OH YES! Thank you so much for linking me that! This is amazing! I'll never have to boot into Windows again! (well, except to play Minecraft, which is odd, considering it's a Java-based game. Please help if you can: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2082890 )

Answer (score 1):

No, this is impossible. Sorry. :(

Silverlight is proprietary; run by Microsoft, if I'm not mistaken. As for the sites that don't work with Moonlight, well, you're screwed unless you can get Virtualbox to work for you.

Moonlight works with Firefox these days (I'm running 19.0 right now, and it's working,) but, so far, I have never, ever, seen a single thing that supported Moonlight: video, service, *anything*.

If you've installed Moonlight on your Firefox after updating, but it still appears not to work, I'd recommend contacting the site's feedback centre to let them know how much you'd appreciate Moonlight support.

Answer (score 0):

Is is possible now thanks to the trick shown at the end of this answer:

https://askubuntu.com/a/219068/15943

(uses `wine` and Firefox for Windows in Ubuntu).